# How to plug txyam on top of tornado IOLoop

Tags: memcached, twisted, tornado

I 've tried to use tornado.platform.twisted to integrate txyam memcached client, but when I try to check it for functioning, next error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "swcomet/tx_memcache_helper.py", line 32, in <module>
mem_helper = MemcacheHelper()
File "swcomet/tx_memcache_helper.py", line 19, in __init__
self.add(4)
File "/home/rustem/work/sw.services.swcomet.python/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 117, in wrapper
gen = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "swcomet/tx_memcache_helper.py", line 25, in add
self.mem.getPickled(user_id, decompress=True)
File "/home/rustem/work/sw.services.swcomet.python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/txyam/client.py", line 133, in getPickled
return self.get(key, **kwargs).addCallback(handleResult, uncompress)
File "/home/rustem/work/sw.services.swcomet.python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/txyam/client.py", line 27, in wrapper
func = getattr(self.getClient(key), cmd)
File "/home/rustem/work/sw.services.swcomet.python/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/txyam/client.py", line 48, in getClient
raise NoServerError, "No connected servers remaining."
```

txyam.client.NoServerError: No connected servers remaining.

The source code which dumps that error:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.gen
from txyam.client import YamClient
from swtools.date import _ts
import tornado.platform.twisted

MEMHOSTS = ['127.0.0.1111']
USER_EXPIRATION_TIME = 61


class MemcacheHelper(object):
   def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
     try:
        self.mem = YamClient(["127.0.0.1"])
     except Exception, e:
        print "ERror", e
     self.clients = set()
     self.add(4)

  @tornado.gen.engine
  def add(self, user_id, expire=None):
     self.clients.add(user_id)
     expire = expire or USER_EXPIRATION_TIME
     self.mem.getPickled(user_id, decompress=True)
     print "hmmm"

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "trying to start on top of IOLOOP"
    ioloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    #reactor = TornadoReactor(ioloop)
    mem_helper = MemcacheHelper()
    #mem_helper.add(4)
    ioloop.start()
```

Please, help me to solve this problem!

Comment: Why not use an async driver for memcached and tornado? Something like this: https://github.com/dpnova/tornado-memcache

Answer (score 1):

txyam appears not to let you perform any memcache operations until after at least one connection has been established:

```
def getActiveConnections(self):
    return [factory.client for factory in self.factories if not factory.client is None]


def getClient(self, key):
    hosts = self.getActiveConnections()
    log.msg("Using %i active hosts" % len(hosts))
    if len(hosts) == 0:
        raise NoServerError, "No connected servers remaining."
    return hosts[ketama(key) % len(hosts)]
```

It attempts to set up these connections right away:

```
def __init__(self, hosts):
    """                                                                                                                                                                                       
    @param hosts: A C{list} of C{tuple}s containing hosts and ports.                                                                                                                          
    """
    self.connect(hosts)
```

But connection setup is asynchronous, and it doesn't expose an event to indicate when at least one connection has been established.

So your code fails because you call `add` right away, before any connections exist.  A good long-term fix would be to file a bug report against txyam, because this isn't a very nice interface.  `YamClient` could have a `whenReady` method that returns a `Deferred` that fires when you are actually allowed to use the `YamClient` instance.  Or there could be an alternate constructor that returns a `Deferred` that fires with the `YamClient` instance, but only after it can be used.

Comment: Thank you. You are definitely write. The problem is in buildProtocol method. connectTCP returns a connector instance, while buildProtocol executes further asynchronously. So could you right me an example, how you can solve that problem. I've tried to add deferred which will be exectuted, when protocol between client and server is built.